# nashorn replace Java.type with binding

Tags: java-8, nashorn

To invoke Java from JS you can use `Java.type`. Is there a way to bind a java class in the Bindings?

So replace:

```
scriptEngine.eval("Java.type('my.own.AwesomeObj')");
```

with something like:

```
Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
bindings.put("AwesomeObj", my.own.AwesomeObj.class);
scriptEngine.setBindings(bingings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
```

I am working on a framework where I want to make a lot of classes available for the js scripts, and preferably **not** use a *string concatenation* and an *eval*. Currently it throws an exception with message: AwesomeObj is not a function, what makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nashorn distinguishes a type from a `java.lang.Class` instance, just like Java does (in Java language, `my.own.AwesomeObj` is a type, while `my.own.AwesomeObj.class` is an instance of `java.lang.Class`. You can use a type to access static members, or as a constructor. You can't use a `Class` object for that purpose. The bad news is, you can't directly obtain the object that Nashorn uses for representing types; it's an instance of `jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.StaticClass` and it lives in a restricted package. However, you can evaluate it in script with

```
engine.eval("Java.type('my.own.AwesomeObj')");
```

and put the result of that in the bindings. Incidentally, within Nashorn, if you put the `Class` object into bindings under name `AwesomeObjClass`, you can use the synthetic property `.static` to obtain the type, e.g.:

```
var AwesomeObj = AwesomeObjClass.static;
```

In this sense, `.static` on a Class object is the dual of `.class` on a type object (`.static` obviously doesn't exist in Java, where types aren't reified as runtime objects).

```
var stringType = Java.type("java.lang.String");
var stringClass = stringType.class
print(stringClass instanceof java.lang.Class); // true
print(stringType === stringClass.static); // true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Attila for the answer! I have found the `StaticClass` during my investigation, it is sad it is internal now, maybe later there will be a better interface to the nashorn internals. I will go for 'the eval per classes' option.

Answer (score 1):

since Java 9 you can use `jdk.dynalink.beans.StaticClass.forClass` as it is not internal anymore:

```
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("AwesomeObj", StaticClass.forClass(my.own.AwesomeObj.class));
```

then you can utilize the binding in the JS code with :

```
var awesome = new AwesomeObj();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your top-level script of your framework do:

```
var AwesomeObj = Java.type("my.own.AwesomeObj");
```

Comment: Thanks! True, but I do not have any top level script.

Comment: My advice would be to have a top-level script. It'll be less awkward to look into this stuff if you make the bridge between Java and JS as thin as possible; it's very easy to access this stuff on the JS stuff and (as you've found) harder to do it on the Java side in this instance.

Otherwise you've got to head into Nashorn non-public APIs, which can and will change (I had my code break between 1.8.0 and 1.8.0u20 with an internal class I was using).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, maybe I will need a top level script later, for these injections only, I will try to avoid it.

Comment: you mean ScriptEngine.setContext()? or .getContext().setAttribute() ? I mean, every time I run a script I will have to prepend with these js references or I can let it pre-setup in some way?